# is there a way to integrate a switch with String.contains("")?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I need to check if a String object contains() various substrings and based on the results have different pieces of code execute.  Currently I have a series of else if.  I would like to convert it into a switch if possible.  Is there a way to do this?

currently:

```
 if (SomeString.contains("someSubString")) {

    . . . do something

 } else if (SomeString.contains("anotherSubString")) {

    . . . do something else

 } else if (SomeString.contains("yetanotherSubString")) {

    . . . do something even more different

 }  
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: No. You can't do that.

Comment: although switch statements with String cases have been implemented in Java SE 7

Comment: Java 7 allows you to write switch-case with Strings, but you still can't use `contains` or any boolean-returning method. `if-else` is the only way here.

Comment: If you have a lot of such tests you might want to use a map<substring, action>, and use a loop to test them.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why?  Are you sure testing substrings is the best approach?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When I have a situation like this, and really don't want to use `else if`, I do something like this:

```
String[] cases = {"someSubString", "anotherSubString", "yetanotherSubString"};

int i;
for(i = 0; i < cases.length; i++)
    if(SomeString.contains(cases[i])) break;

switch(i) {
    case 0: //someSubString
        System.out.println("do something");
    break;
    case 1: //anotherSubString
        System.out.println("do something else");
    break;
    case 2: //yetanotherSubString
        System.out.println("do something even more different");
    break;
    default:
        System.out.println("do nothing");
}
```

Of course, that has a couple of downsides. For starters, if you add another strings anywhere but the end, all the indices will shift, and you have to correct for that manually. Still, I think I have used something like that once or twice and thought it makes the code more readable. Presumably, the indices had some meaning in the program, thus coupling the `0...someSubString` in a way meaningful to the problem.

Comment: If you make cases an enum with the different substrings as values, you could use the same idea and it wouldn't break if you add substrings, since the switch would be on the enums rather than indices.

Comment: you mean something like `for(...) if(SomeString.contains(currentEnum.getValue())) break;`, and `switch(currentEnum) {...}`? In that case, I'd use `currentEnum.doSomething();` instead of the `switch` anyway

Comment: No, I mean something like `enum Cases { SOME("someSubString"), ANOTHER("anotherSubString"), ...}  Cases i;  for (i : Cases.values()) if(SomeString.contains(i.getSubstring()) break;  switch(i) { ... }`

Comment: And then I read your comment again.  Yes, that's what I mean, and yes, that would be a better way to do it. :)

Comment: i was just about to ask what's the difference^^ ok then ;)

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, it can be made better though - I'll do an answer.

Comment: See my answer. By using objects you can avoid the arbitrary mapping of indexes to code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a String variable in a switch, but you can use a char, maybe a specific char is diferent in all your strings?

For "someSubString", "anotherSubString" and "yetanotherSubString" you can use something like:

```
switch(SomeString.chatAt(0)) {
    case 's':
    case 'a':
    case 'y':
}
```

But this is only valid if you know all possible values of the string and a character of a specific position is diferent on all of them.

Comment: it should be charAt instead of chatAt

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 you can switch on complete Strings, but not on partial skins. What you can do though is a strategy pattern to handle this sort of situation.

```
private abstract class StringProcessor {
    String pattern;

    StringProcessor(String str) {
        pattern = str;
    }

    boolean matches(String str) {
        return str.matches(pattern);
    }

    abstract void process(String str);
}

StringProcessor[] processors = new StringProcessor[] {
    new StringProcessor("patt1") {
        void process(String str) {
            // do stuff for patt1
        }
    },
    new StringProcessor("patt2") {
        void process(String str) {
            // do stuff for patt2
        }
    }

};
```

Then in your method:

```
for (StringProcessor sp: processors) {
    if (sp.matches(str)) {
        sp.process(str);
        break; // Don't break if you want the option to handle all that match
    }
}
```

Now you can add as many different StringProcessors as you want and the will all get checked and if any match the code will be called. In many cases you can pre define the list of processors ahead of time but if need be you can create it dynamically too.

Comment: obviously I like mine better^^ for a serious situation, this could be the way to go, but I don't like solving problems in a single method ("how do I write this `switch`?") by adding entire classes (counting the anonymous classes, we have three). Just like the enum approach (with constant-specific action methods, this results in the same number of classes), this has the additional problem that you could not use (nonfinal) local variables of the original method.

Comment: Variables from the original method can be passed into process (or made final as you say). The switch structure is inherently fragile and as soon as you have more than a few options it is going to be incredibly easy to lose track of what case corresponds to what option. Keep in mind too that in Java 8 closures should make the syntax for creating the processors much smaller as well.

Answer (score 0):

For same type of situation i used as below.
First got all string which i am looking into as a string

`String str ="someSubString,anotherSubString,yetanotherSubString"`

Then get the list out of above string

`List items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\s*,\s*"));`

Now loop above list and use contain and switch

```
<pre>
  for (String item : items) {
            if (mainStr.contains(item)) {
                switch (item) {
                    case "someSubString":
                        do something
                        break;
                    case "anotherSubString":
                        do something else
                        break;
                    case "yetanotherSubString":
                        do something even more different
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
</pre>
```

Hope this will help guys who may be looking for same type of requirement now.