# switch elseif to switch case

Tags: c#, if-statement, c#-4.0, switch-statement

How can we switch the below if -else statements to switch case statement .. can anyone help on this ...

```
        if (Webcc1.Contains(licensePartID))
        {
             dtExpiryDate = dtActivatedDate.AddYears(1);
            int isExpiry = DateTime.Compare(dtActivatedDate, dtExpiryDate);
             if (isExpiry >= 0)
             {
                    setError(lblSystemErr, "This action cannot be performed. The subscription period of the license key has expired");
                    return;
              }
         }
        else if (Webcc3.Contains(licensePartID))
        {
           dtExpiryDate = dtActivatedDate.AddYears(3);
           int isExpiry = DateTime.Compare(dtActivatedDate, dtExpiryDate);
            if (isExpiry >= 0)
             {
                  setError(lblSystemErr, "This action cannot be performed. The subscription period of the license key has expired");
                   return;
             }
         }
         else if (Webcc5.Contains(licensePartID))
         {
            dtExpiryDate = dtActivatedDate.AddYears(5);
            int isExpiry = DateTime.Compare(dtActivatedDate, dtExpiryDate);
            if (isExpiry >= 0)
            {
               setError(lblSystemErr, "This action cannot be performed. The subscription period of the license key has expired");
               return;
             }
         }
```

many thanks in advance ....

Comment: You can't. Switch statements don't work like that. If it were `Webcc3 == licensePartID`, you'd have a chance

Comment: there is your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255198/is-there-a-way-to-integrate-a-switch-with-string-contains

Comment: @Rob: The impossible just takes a while longer ;-)

Comment: @Rob you downvoted becoz it is impossible :P

Comment: @EnigmaState I didn't downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it directly, but you can use a <strike>bitwise operation</strike> ternary condition to convert your if...else if into a switch statement:

```
var flags = (Webcc1.Contains(licensePartID)) ? 1 : 0;
flags |= (Webcc3.Contains(licensePartID)) ? 2 : 0;
flags |= (Webcc5.Contains(licensePartID)) ? 4 : 0;
```

```
var flags = (Webcc1.Contains(licensePartID)) ? 1 :
            (Webcc3.Contains(licensePartID)) ? 2 :
            (Webcc5.Contains(licensePartID)) ? 4 :
            0;
switch(flags)
{
    case 1:
        dtExpiryDate = dtActivatedDate.AddYears(1);
        int isExpiry = DateTime.Compare(dtActivatedDate, dtExpiryDate);
        if (isExpiry >= 0)
        {
            setError(lblSystemErr, "This action cannot be performed. The subscription period of the license key has expired");
            return;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        dtExpiryDate = dtActivatedDate.AddYears(3);
        int isExpiry = DateTime.Compare(dtActivatedDate, dtExpiryDate);
        if (isExpiry >= 0)
        {
            setError(lblSystemErr, "This action cannot be performed. The subscription period of the license key has expired");
            return;
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        dtExpiryDate = dtActivatedDate.AddYears(5);
        int isExpiry = DateTime.Compare(dtActivatedDate, dtExpiryDate);
        if (isExpiry >= 0)
        {
            setError(lblSystemErr, "This action cannot be performed. The subscription period of the license key has expired");
            return;
        }
        break;
}
}
```

However, the code sample you provided can and should be shorter, since the only thing that is changed between the conditions is the number of years to add, you can simply do this:

```
var numberOfYears = (Webcc1.Contains(licensePartID)) ? 1 :
                    (Webcc3.Contains(licensePartID)) ? 3 :
                    (Webcc5.Contains(licensePartID)) ? 5 :
                    0; // or some other default number if needed
dtExpiryDate = dtActivatedDate.AddYears(numberOfYears);
int isExpiry = DateTime.Compare(dtActivatedDate, dtExpiryDate);
if (isExpiry >= 0)
{
    setError(lblSystemErr, "This action cannot be performed. The subscription period of the license key has expired");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hi Zohar many thanks .... what if i don't have any default number to put at the end .. i need to check only three conditions itself ...

Comment: In that case, simply check if the `numberOfYears` is not `0` before performing the test.